# cakephp - get Projects of a specific category

Tags: cakephp, controller

i'm not getting acess a category of a specific project. 
MODELS AND RELATIONS

- 1 Project has many ProjectCategory (the intermediate table is NodeAssociation)
- I used a hasAndBelongsToMany relation

  /*Model Project*/

  ```
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
      'ProjectCategory' => array(
          'className' => 'ProjectCategory',
          'joinTable' => 'NodeAssociation',
          'foreignKey' => 'skin_node_id',
          'associationForeignKey' => 'source_node_id'
      )
  );
  ```

/*SQL*/

SELECT pc.id, pc.cname AS category

FROM project p

JOIN nodeassociation na

ON  p.id = na.source_node_id and p.id=10001

JOIN projectcategory pc

ON na.sink_node_id = pc.id AND sink_node_entity = 'ProjectCategory' ;

```
FUNCTION in ProjectsController

    $joins = array(
                array('table' => 'nodeassociation',
                    'alias' => 'NodeAssociation',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Project.id = NodeAssociation.source_node_id',
                    )
                ),
                array('table' => 'projectcategory',
                    'alias' => 'ProjectCategory',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'NodeAssociation.sink_node_id = ProjectCategory.id', "NodeAssociation.sink_node_entity='ProjectCategory'"
                    )
                )
            );

            $categories = $this->Project->ProjectCategory->find('all', array('joins' => $joins,
                'fields' => array('ProjectCategory.id, ProjectCategory.cname'),
                'recursive' => -1,
                'conditions' => array('Project.id' => 10001)));
```

the error appears to me is

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERRO: faltando entrada para tabela "Project" na cláusula FROM LINE 1: ...ublic"."nodeassociation" AS "NodeAssociation" ON ("Project".... ^
```

what am I doing wrong?

best regards

Comment: If you're trying to follow Cake conventions, your table names should be underscored plural.  I can't read that error, but it looks like it can't find the "Project" table?

Comment: I can not change the database. :/ and yes, it cant find the Project table.

Comment: Is there a Project table?

Comment: yes, the table is called project (p - small letter)

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your Project model:

```
public $useTable = 'project';
```